# How to auto update account balance in database every 30 days

Tags: php, mysql, auto-update

I have a customer table in my database. This table contains customer information including his/her balance.

Now I want to add his/her balance after every 30 days depends on what promo or plan he/she applied

example: he applied for a plan 1599 so after every 30 days his balance must add the price of the plan he applied.

current balance = 0
after 30 days balance = 1599

How will i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a cron job for the same. Check the date difference for every user and if its greater than 30 days add the balance to the respective user's account.

Comment: use a database trigger?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like

1. Store the Date when user choose plan by using `date('Y-m-d')` in a variable
2. Add 30 Days in it by using `date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+7 day", $date))` and save this in database
3. Write a query to check that date of today is equal to that stored date or not if so then add points to that account.

For point 3 you may also need cron job depends on your requirement.

If still need help feel free to comment